# Is it a bad idea to reference a row from a many-to-many table in another many-to-many table

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design, many-to-many

If I have a schema similar to this:

```
TABLE 1  
id  
column  
other_column  
etc

TABLE 2  
id  
table1_id  
some_other_table_id
```

Is it a good idea to add a third table like this:

```
TABLE 3  
id  
table2_id  
row_from_another_table_id
```

**EDIT:**
To make things clearer, consider a schema like this:

```
EVENTS  
id  
name  
other_stuff 

RANGES  
id  
time_from  
time_to  
max_people  
etc

EVENTS_PLACES  
id  
event_id  
place_id
```

What I want to do is to define a time range for an event. But a specific event in a specific place(`EVENTS_PLACES`) can 'overwrite' this ranges. Also an event can have multiple ranges.

I hope this makes the question a little bit more clear now.

Comment: that is what we call a junction table which comes into picture in many to many relation

Comment: @NiladriBiswas: So the question is: Is it a good idea to reference a row from the junction table in another table?

Comment: I would say it depends on your database design and needs you are trying to meet.  It's feasible to do this, I've seen it before, but what exactly are you trying to do?  Or is this just a hypthetical question?

Comment: It's going to be tricky to answer this without understanding the data.  Perhaps a sample query of why you need to structure your table this way would help.  There are cases where this is good and other cases where it would be bad.

Comment: Just trying to understand your schema. It looks like the maximum number of people at an event is related to its time range rather than its place and that the place is not related time range.

Comment: @Jodrell: The idea is that a specific event can have a specific range depending on the place. But if that specific range is not defined, the "default" one is used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its always been my impression that a many to many relationship is a violation [Boyce-Codd Normal Form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyce%E2%80%93Codd_normal_form) and therefore a violation of a good relational database schema.

Therefore, relating data to a link table is, infact, necessary to achieve BCNF and therefore good. If avoiding data update anomolies is good.

---

On to the specific schema example you presented. I think you want these logical tables (or entities),

```
-----------------------
EventClass
-----------------------
Id
Name
... Other attributes common to every instance
-
-----------------------
TimeSlot
-----------------------
Id
Start
End
-
-----------------------
Place
-----------------------
Id
Name
Address
MaxAttendance
... etc
-
----------------------
EventInstance
-----------------------
Id
EventClassId
TimeSlotId
PlaceId
PresenterName
...Other attributes specific to the instance
```

`EventInstance` is a realtionship between `EventClass`, `TimeSlot` and `Place`, any attributes specific to the `EventInstance` should be stored on that entity. Any attributes common to a related group of events should be stored on the `EventClass` attribute.

---

Its all a question of [Database Normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization), generally speaking, the more normalized the data the better. However, there is a case for compromise when performance is a concern, if the desired data is stored in the output format it does make a select query simpler and faster although, updates might be hell.

I would counteract the case for compromise by suggesting that, with the right Indecies, [Materialized Views](http://www.fromdual.com/mysql-materialized-views) and, indecies on [Materialized Views](http://www.fromdual.com/mysql-materialized-views), you can get the best of both worlds. The maintainability of fully normalized data with the speed of performance. Although, it does require some skill and consideration to get the schema right.

Comment: My idea was, that an event will be defined with a "default" timeslot, and only if an event instance has a different timeslot it should be mentioned.

Comment: @xyu You needn't necessarily have the default time slot in the database. Alternatively, you could add it as the `TimeSlot` with `Id` `1` then put a DEFAULT CONSTRAINT on `EventInstance.TimeSlotId` of `1` and make the column `NOT NULL`. Either way, its an implementation detail and not part of a Entity Relationship Diagram or logical design.

Comment: @xyu, the actual best design depends largely on what you are trying to model, something I have a passing knowledge of. I've used your initial schema to show that yes, link tables are good (hopefully.)

Comment: The point was that every event definition has a default slot, but anyway the question was abstract. I'm not trying to do anything, just wondering if this type of schema is considerable.

Comment: I have used that kind of approach for a project and it didn't do bad, but I was hoping to hear from others about their experience with something similar.

Comment: @xyu I've extended my answer slightly with my final thoughts.

Answer (score 1):

So you have a relation between two tables with properties, and you have a subclass of that relation with some more properties. This is rare but possible.

Suppose in your polygamous hetero dating site one or more Woman entities has a relation with one or more Man. These two tables may be coupled with a junction table, Relationship. Now some of them are married, which you consider a special type of relationship. So Marriage is a subclass of Relationship, and the Marriage table has a reference to the id in the Relationship  table.

Of course, it may be simpler to solve such situations in another way, for example to simply have two junction tables between Man and Woman. But there are certainly situations in which you would want to extend on the relationship in the junction table.

Comment: Yup, I'm in a situation, in which i want to extend the junction table, but the question was: is this a good idea?

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to add a column to your TABLE2 that describes the nature of the connection between "things". For example, a PERSON table and a RELATIONSHIPS table, you model your "objects" in the first table, then the "links" in the seconds, e.g.

```
+---------+---------+-------+--------+
| link_id | from_id | to_id |  type  |
+---------+---------+-------+--------+
|       1 |       2 |     3 | Mother |
|       2 |       8 |     3 | Sister |
+---------+---------+-------+--------+
```

With appropriate indices, this means you can do things like find all relationships for a given person, or find everyone who has a sister, etc. This is a simple example, but it starts to get interesting when the from_id and to_id can be different types of object i.e. not just people.

I'd used this approach in the past when working with a very generic schema that was aggregating data from a variety of other sources and had to be flexible. Clearly there's a trade-off between flexibility and e.g. speed, query complexity. You have to decide whether it's useful in your case.